# Is it possible to get getLocaleString() value in Java in XPages?

Tags: java, xpages

Is it possible to get the `getLocaleString()` value in Java in `XPages`?
In `SSJS` I can get it as below -

```
context.getLocaleString() ;
```

Is something similar available in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this before:

```
return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the XSPContext object by doing this:

```
XSPContext context = XSPContext.getXSPContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
context.getLocaleString();
```

You can also use ExtLibUtil from XPages Extension Library to get the XSPContext object:

```
com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil.getXspContext();
```

So you can do this to get the locale string:

```
ExtLibUtil.getXspContext().getLocaleString();
```